# How to make a multiple route?

Tags: search, routes, slug

Can't figure out how to create a dynamic route for the categories in this format:

```
site.com/news/category-1-and-category-2-and-category-3
```

That would bring the results from these slug categories.

Trying to build a complex query and I'm sure there is bound to be a better way of doing it that.

```
'news/<categories:.*>/<categorySlugs:{slug}(\-and\-{slug})+>' => ['template' => 'news/index']
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried processing the entire slug directly in your template, without setting a complex route? Check for the presence of the string "-and-", split the slug accordingly, build a Category query.